# how to convert html/php codes into doc using phpword in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, phpword

I am using Phpword to create doc files in laravel. code below works fine.

```
    public function downloaddoc(){
    $wordTest = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

    $newSection = $wordTest->addSection();

    $desc1 = "The Portfolio details is a very useful feature of the web page. You can establish your archived details and the works to the entire web community. It was outlined to bring in extra clients, get you selected based on this details.";

    $newSection->addText($desc1, array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 15, 'color' => 'red'));

    $objectWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($wordTest, 'Word2007');
try {
    $objectWriter->save(storage_path('TestWordFile.docx'));
} catch (Exception $e) {
}

return response()->download(storage_path('TestWordFile.docx'));
}
```

But i want to convert some html/php codes into a doc file. can it convert a php file into a doc file like we do in pdf.?
if yes then how. If not than what are alternative solutions.?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using `$text = file_get_contents('/path/to/php/file.php'); $newSection->addText($text)` or are you wanting the PHP to be parsed and rendered in the Word Document as if it were being viewed from a browser or limited in some way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that can be accomplished by [Heredoc Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/flexible_heredoc_nowdoc_syntaxes)

Doing like so wouldn't parse the PHP syntax inside it.

```
<?php
$code = <<<EOT
<?php
$var = "string";
?>
EOT;
echo $code;
?>
```

will output as it is:

```
<?php
 $var = "string";
?>
```

Comment: You would want to use [`NOWDOC`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc), since `HEREDOC` would parse the variables within it. Click https://3v4l.org/vS1ti for example.